# conditional statement for active permalinks

Tags: permalinks

I'm looking for a way to create an if...else statement hinging on whether pretty permalinks are active or not. So I need something which returns true when permalinks are changed from the default.

```
if (pretty_permalinks_are_on) {
   do this;
    } else {
       do that;
    }
```

Sort of thing. Just have no idea about the 'pretty_permalinks_are_on' part.

If anyone would extend the hand of compassion and throw some crumbs to a php noob, I'd be a grateful learner :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_option( 'permalink_structure' )` is your friend. If you're using the default it will be set as an empty string:

```
if( get_option( 'permalink_structure' ) !== '' ) {
    // custom permalink enabled code
} else {
    // no permalink 
}
```